# General coefficient of a Taylor series of $\frac{1}{e^{(e^{1-x})+\frac{x}{2}}+e^{\frac{x}{2}}}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, power-series, taylor-expansion

Is it possible to write a general Taylor coefficient of the function $$\frac{1}{e^{(e^{1-x})+\frac{x}{2}}+e^{\frac{x}{2}}}?$$

Wolfram alpha produces [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series+1%2F%28e%5E%28%28e%5E%281-x%29%29%2B%28x%2F2%29%29%2Be%5E%28x%2F2%29%29) nasty thing.

Comment: Well first point you can factorize and use series of $\frac{1}{x+1}$ and see if there is a plausible way to find the coefficient .Good luck !

Comment: Since $e^{1-x}>0$, $e^{e^{1-x}}>1$, so you can't use the series for $1/(X+1)$

Comment: With Laurent'series it works I think .

Comment: Not totally kidding : the nightmare is not the result but the expression you want to expand.

Comment: Why do you care about this? Is it just out of curiosity, or is there context to this question?

Comment: If you just care about the asymptotic behavior of the Taylor coefficients for large indices, just find the poles closest to the origin and residues at them. Otherwise, the answer is, indeed, ugly and nothing can be done about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Factoring the expression: $$\frac{1}{e^{\frac{x}{2}}} \cdot \frac{1}{e^{e^{1-x}}+1} = e^{-\frac{x}{2}} \cdot \frac{1}{1+e^{e^{1-x}}}$$

The series for the first term is given by $$e^{-\frac{x}{2}} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^n}{n!}x^n \tag 1$$

Focusing on $\frac{1}{1+e^{e^{1-x}}}$ now, using the series for the [Sigmoid function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SigmoidFunction.html), this is $$\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{-\left(2^{2n}-1\right)B_{2n}}{\left(2n\right)!}e^{(1-x)(2n-1)}$$

where $B_n$ are the Bernoulli numbers.

Then using the expansion of $e^x$, this comes out to $$\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{-\left(2^{2n}-1\right)B_{2n}\ e^{\left(2n-1\right)}}{\left(2n\right)!}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(1-2n\right)^{m}}{m!}x^{m}$$

Switching the order of summation yields $$\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}x^{m}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{-\left(2^{2n}-1\right)B_{2n}\ e^{\left(2n-1\right)}}{\left(2n\right)!}\frac{\left(1-2n\right)^{m}}{m!}$$

Expanding the $(1-2n)^m$ and simplifying yields $$\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}x^{m} 
\sum_{k=0}^m \frac{\binom{m}{k} (-2)^k}{m! \ e} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{B_{2n}}{\left(2n\right)!} n^k (e^{2n} - e^{2n}2^{2n}) \tag 2$$

Let $f_k(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{B_{2n}\ }{\left(2n\right)!} n^k x^n$. Then $f_{k+1}(x) = xf_k'(x)$ with $f(x) = f_0(x) = -1 + \frac{\sqrt{x}}{2} \coth\left( \frac{\sqrt{x}}{2} \right)$

Then $$f_k(x) = \sum_{p=0}^k S(k, p) x^p f^{(p)}(x) \tag 3$$ where $S(k, p)$ are the [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind). The innermost summation of $(2)$ can be expressed as $f_k\left(e^2\right) - f_k\left(4e^2\right)$

This then means that $$\frac{1}{1+e^{e^{1-x}}} = \frac{1}{2}+\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}x^{m} 
\sum_{k=0}^m \frac{\binom{m}{k} (-2)^k}{m! \ e} \left(f_k\left(e^2\right) - f_k\left(4e^2\right)\right) \tag 4$$

Multiplying $(1)$ and $(4)$ shows that $$\frac{1}{e^{(e^{1-x})+\frac{x}{2}}+e^{\frac{x}{2}}} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n \left(\frac{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n}}{2\ n!} + \sum_{m=0}^n \sum_{k=0}^m \frac{\binom{m}{k} (-2)^k}{m! \ e} \frac{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-m}}{(n-m)!} \left(f_k\left(e^2\right) - f_k\left(4e^2\right)\right) \right)$$

Plugging $(3)$ into this expands this to $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n \left(\underbrace{\frac{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n}}{2\ n!} + \sum_{m=0}^n \sum_{k=0}^m \sum_{p=0}^k \frac{\binom{m}{k} (-2)^k}{m!} \frac{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-m}}{(n-m)!}   S(k, p) e^{2p-1} \left(f^{(p)}(e^2) - 4^p f^{(p)}(4e^2)\right)}_{a_n} \right)$$

Switching the order of summation so that $m$ is the innermost sum simplifies $a_n$ to $$\frac{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n}}{2\ n!} + \sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{p=0}^k (-2)^k S(k, p) e^{2p-1} \left(f^{(p)}(e^2) - 4^p f^{(p)}(4e^2)\right) \frac{2^{k-n}}{k!(n-k)!} \tag 5$$

Now focusing on $f^{(p)}(x)$, where $f(x) = -1 + \frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}\coth\left( \frac{\sqrt{x}}{2} \right)$: The $p$-th derivative (for $p \ge 1$) would be, using [Faà di Bruno's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula): $$\sum_{j=1}^p \frac{d^j}{dt^j} (t\coth(t)) \Big|_{t=\sqrt{x}/2} B_{p, j}\left( \frac{(-1)^{1+1} (2\cdot 1-3)!!}{2^{1+1} x^{1-\frac{1}{2}}}, ..., \frac{(-1)^{p-j+1+1} (2 (p-j+1)-3)!!}{2^{p-j+1+1} x^{p-j+1-\frac{1}{2}}} \right) \tag 6$$

where $B_{p, j}$ denotes the [Bell polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials).

"Zooming" in to $\frac{d^j}{dt^j} (t \coth(t))$: This is equal to (using the [general Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule)) $$\sum_{i=0}^{j} \binom{j}{i} b_{j-i} (t) \frac{d^i}{dt^i} \text{csch}(t)$$

where $b_{n}(t)$ is $t\cosh(t) + n\sinh(t)$ if $n$ is even and $n\cosh(t) + t\sinh(t)$ if $n$ is odd.

> I originally had an extremely complicated (even worse than this!) formula for $\frac{d^i}{dt^i} \text{csch}(t)$ using Faà di Bruno's formula, but I decided to scrap that and just used Wolfram Alpha to find the derivative.

Using [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=nth+derivative+of+csch%28x%29), this simplifies to

$$\sum_{i=0}^{j} \binom{j}{i} b_{j-i} (t) \text{csch}(t) \sum_{h=0}^i \sum_{g=0}^h (-1)^g 2^{h-g} \binom{i}{h} (1 + \coth(t))^g g! S(h, g) \tag 7$$

If I plugged $(7)$ into $(6)$, and then plugged that into $(5)$, the result would be a very long expression, but would result in a "closed form" for $a_n$.

Edit: I managed to find (partially by guessing, but I was able to prove it) that the Bell polynomial in $(6)$ is $$\frac{(-1)^{p-j} (2(p-j)-1)!! \binom{2p-j-1}{j-1}}{2^{p+j} x^{p - \frac{j}{2}}}$$

This then simplifies $(6)$, which is $f^{(p)}(x)$, to $$\sum_{j=1}^p \frac{d^j}{dt^j} (t\coth(t)) \Big|_{t=\sqrt{x}/2} \frac{(-1)^{p-j} (2(p-j)-1)!! \binom{2p-j-1}{j-1}}{2^{p+j} x^{p - \frac{j}{2}}} \tag {6.1}$$

Also using the fact that $S(k, 0) = 0$ for $k \ge 1$ makes $(5)$ into $$\frac{(-1)^n - \tanh(e/2)}{2^{n+1}\ n!} + \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{p=1}^k (-2)^k S(k, p) e^{2p-1} \left(f^{(p)}(e^2) - 4^p f^{(p)}(4e^2)\right) \frac{2^{k-n}}{k!(n-k)!} \tag {5.1}$$

Plugging $(6.1)$ into $(5.1)$ yields $$\frac{(-1)^n - \tanh(e/2)}{2^{n+1}\ n!} + \frac{1}{2^n n!}\sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{p=1}^k \sum_{j=1}^p (-1)^k 2^{2k} \binom{n}{k} S(k, p) e^{j-1}  \frac{(-1)^{p-j} (2(p-j)-1)!! \binom{2p-j-1}{j-1}}{2^p} \left(  \frac{1}{2^{j}}\frac{d^j}{dt^j} (t\coth(t)) \Big|_{t=e/2} - \frac{d^j}{dt^j} (t\coth(t)) \Big|_{t=e}\right) $$

Comment: Nice. Faa di Bruno's formula excites me every time :)

Comment: @K.defaoite I actually learned about it while answering this question, and it seems incredibly useful. To be honest though, I was trying to avoid using it because it is somewhat long/unwieldy.

Comment: Indeed the summation range (or Bell polynomials, if you go about it that way) does make this formula rather complicated. But it is still a beautiful piece of mathematics.

Comment: Thanks! I just can't believe what I am seeing! So if the computer(wolfram alpha) fails, we have got @VarunVejalla

Comment: @mathisgood Thanks for the compliments (although I'm not sure they are completely deserved, since I did end up using Wolfram Alpha in my edit)! Just curious, but what was your question for?

Comment: @VarunVejalla It arises in one of my research problems related to integral equations where I am supposed to integrate term by term. Irrespective of its origin, your solution method is independently worthy.